# Increase display resolution using Microsoft Basic Display Adapter on Windows Server 2019 due to lack of AMD drivers

Tags: drivers, display, windows-server, display-driver, amd-ryzen

Please, any way to increase the display resolution while using Microsoft Basic Display Adapter on Windows Server 2019? It runs on **800x600 only**, I need to get onto 1024x768 at least.

We've got the *AMD Ryzen 9 7950X* (with integrated graphics) on the *ASROCK X670E Steel Legend* motherboard. The problem is that either ASROCK's or AMD official drivers do NOT work - they refuse to install due to ***Error 184 unsupported OS***.

So whether there is some way to install the drivers onto the Windows Server 2019 (? asking here [How to install AMD display (graphics) drivers on Windows Server 2019 standard?](https://superuser.com/questions/1826612/how-to-install-amd-display-graphics-drivers-on-windows-server-2019-standard)) or I need to manually override somehow the almost-unusable 800x600 - it is really painful to manage the server in oldschool SVGA resolution...

PS: I do not understand why the drivers do not work, since WS 2019 whould be using the same kernel as Windows 10 do, right?!

Comment: Questions: Have you installed/enabled the "Desktop Experience" (not sure how it is exactly called) feature on your server? This sometimes lets applications designed for W10/W11 work on Server. Which build of Server2019 are you on? (The older ones pre-date his CPU/GPU.) And does Microsoft offer a new driver via Windows Update (check Optional Updates.)

Comment: according to this (and other) article(s) http://www.davidhill.co/2017/04/install-windows-server-2016-gui-desktop-experience/ the "desktop experience" is already included in Windows Server 2019 Standard. I have checked for the presence of the "Windows Media Player" and it's there...

Comment: I see and you are right. That leaves my other questions.

Comment: Windows update states "You're up to date" and the version is "1809", build "17763.5329"

Comment: Do you need Server 2019? Server 2022 might have better support for Ryzen 7000 Series processors...

Comment: Well, to pay non-trivial money for a new Server OS just to increase resolution slightly is not what I want... We are using virtuals anyways, but still, sometimes there is a need to change something in Hyper-V or so... and doing it in SVGA is very unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

Even tough your Windows version (1809) says it is up2date (as you indicate in the comments) it is not the LATEST version of Server 2019.
And you will need a NEWER version of Server 2019 (at least the 23H1 version, possibly 22H2 will work too) in order to able to have the OS recognize the much more recent AMD CPU/GPU combo and offer the standard Microsoft drivers as optional updates via Windows Update.
Your OS is simply too old to know about these new chipsets.

Installing the Feature update packs to get it at 22H2 or later and then re-checking the optional updates for drivers for the AMD CPU/GPU should fix your issue.

Comment: Well, we've got build `17763.5329` and according to Microsoft, as you may see here https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/windows-server/get-started/windows-server-release-info it is, indeed, the very latest build available -  so how could I possibly get any "22H2"?