# How to install AMD display (graphics) drivers on Windows Server 2019 standard?

Tags: windows, drivers, graphics-card, windows-server, amd-ryzen

We've got the *AMD Ryzen 9 7950X* (with integrated graphics) on the *ASROCK X670E Steel Legend* motherboard. The problem is that either ASROCK's or AMD official drivers do NOT work - they refuse to install due to ***Error 184 unsupported OS***.

How do I install the display drivers? Isn't Windows Server 2019 quite the same as Windows 10? It should be perfectly compatible...

Related issue here [Increase display resolution using Microsoft Basic Display Adapter on Windows Server 2019 due to lack of AMD drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/1826596/increase-display-resolution-using-microsoft-basic-display-adapter-on-windows-ser)

Comment: I just googled "`amd Windows Server 2019 Error 184 unsupported OS`" and there are various workarounds

Comment: Have you tried https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/16tr5sm/solution_to_error_184_the_amd_installer_cannot/ (there are [quite a few posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=amd+Windows+Server+2019+Error+184+unsupported+OS+site:www.reddit.com) on Reddit)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6Gb0_GlHj4

Comment: the workaround described here https://www.reddit.com/r/AMDHelp/comments/16tr5sm/solution_to_error_184_the_amd_installer_cannot/?rdt=61090 does not work - the installer says something about incompatible OS anyways

Comment: one down, quite a few to go

Answer (score 1):

A "unsupported OS" error is strange if the driver is for Windows.
I suppose that you used
[this driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-ryzen-processors/amd-ryzen-9-desktop-processors/amd-ryzen-9-7950x).

In case that the problem is with the driver's refusal
to install is because this is a Windows Server edition,
the post
[AMD Drivers installation - Error 184 on Windows Server 2022](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/rnrj9f/amd_drivers_installation_error_184_on_windows/)
has this method of forcing the installation which worked for more
than one person:

> I just finished installing the Windows10/11 drivers on Windows Server
> 2022. Run the amd-software-adrenalin-edition-22.5.2-win10-win11-may23 and let it unpack and fail with the message that it cannot continue.
> Go into device manager and select your graphic device and manually
> install the drivers by pointing it to the folder that the amd install
> put them in, mine was D:\AMD. It will just install the drivers and not
> the software but that is all I wanted.

You may download the software from the post
[AMD Software: Adrenalin Edition 22.5.2 Release Notes](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-rad-win-22-5-2).

Comment: Yes, I have used that driver and tried to manually override the driver, but no luck. I've tried both
a) "Browse my computer for driver software" -> Search for drivers in this location: -> include subfolders (YES). This ends with "The best drivers... already installed". 
b) "Let me pick from a list of..." -> "Have Disk..." -> "C:\AMD\AMD-Software-Installer\Packages\Drivers\Display\WT6A_INF". This ends with "The folder you specified... make sure it is designed to work with Windows for x64-based systems"
:(

Comment: I am trying now the "amd-software-adrenalin-edition-23.12.1-minimalsetup-231205_web.exe" variant... no luck either, there is no "Drivers" subfolder after setup fail in the c:\AMD folder :(

Comment: To find the drivers, use 7Zip to extract all in the `.exe` to a folder. You will find them in the sub-folder `Packages\Drivers`.